# Expand all grid rows by default with rowexpander - EXTJS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am using the rowexpander plugin in a grid.

To expand and collapse all the rows I use a rowexpander override:
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?280175-Issue-with-expand-all-when-using-rowexpander-bufferedgrid

However, the grid must have on render all rows expanded.

I tried the solution of the following fiddle, but without success, giving the error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasCls' of null"

Any idea how to solve this?

FIDDLE:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10bg

EDIT: remove comments on lines 99 and 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [`viewready`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-viewready) event (instead of `afterrender`):

> Fires when the grid view is available (use this for selecting a default row).

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/10bt